# Can we get an "id" back on the help section about meta vote?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, help-center

Recently, the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter) was introduced in order to replace the old FAQ! Which is really nice. But we lost a friend to battle, one minute for "Fragment Identifier", he was a good bro! *We want it back!*

Since votes are a lot different on the meta, we often have to link to the "vote section" of the meta article to help users learn more about the meta! The only problem I see is that now, when we link to the ["help center -> whats meta"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-meta), there is no way to have a direct link to the vote section (which is the one we want to point out!). I understand that users that are redirected to that section should read the whole section and everything, but it would be nice to have an "id" on the **Voting is different on meta** title in order to enable us to link to it like before!

So adding an "id" like *#vote-differences* like it was before would be awesome! And make us able to link to

```
/helpcenter/whats-meta#vote-differences
```

To show directly the section we want to talk about! *(And a beautiful highlight, as pointed out by Doorknob would be awesome! Or ponies, definitely ponies)* Note that this is just one example! Every sub section could/should get one, because most user won't take the time reading a whole page. So if we can link to a specific section, there are more chances that the user read it!

[image: Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!]

As proposed, every "title" (which are currently bees) could get his own ID *(Fragment Identifier)* as it was before, and would gain of being an h2/h3/h<sub>whatEverFits</sub> to really clear up the markup!

Comment: It could maybe highlight that specific section too. +1

Comment: Nice find, and I agree with you.

Comment: +1, I think this suggestion should be expanded to all of the areas of the help section. Stuff in a `<b>` tag should get an ID for direct linking, it would be useful.

Comment: I'm confused why it's in a bold element rather than a header element... It's a title of a new section, it doesn't really continue on from the previous paragraph at all.

Comment: Eeeeek, bees! Run!!!!

Comment: But this would make it easier to pretend that voting on Meta is actually different!

Comment: By the way, it's called a fragment identifier (although, yes, it's implemented using the `id` attribute).

Answer (score -4):

Because of the way we built the employee editing interface, it's not possible to add fragment identifiers without breaking a lot of other stuff.

Besides, the "voting is different" section is the first sub-header of that article - it shouldn't be *that* hard to find, even without being highlighted or jumped to the top. ;)

(I did change those subsections to be headers rather than bold, so they should stand out a little more than before.)

Comment: Assuming the titles themselves won't change much, one can auto-generate an ID based on the text in the title (read: `#voting-is-different-on-meta`). Is it not possible?

Comment: ^ Especially since you already have the code that does this for answer titles.